# iOS7: Navigation bar like dropbox

Tags: ios, objective-c

How can I create a navigation bar item like the "..." of DropBox? So, when user select it, more options appears. Sorry for this question, but I can't find it anywhere.
Dropbox navigation layout: http://cdn.pttrns.com/pttrns/1748/small/IMG_2763.PNG

Comment: I already have a navigation bar and added a navigation bar item "...". Don't know how to open a menu when tap there.

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/jamesvandyne/sspopupheaderview

Answer (score 2):

since the UINavigationController defers most of the action to the controller on top of its stack, you simply need a view inside the controller of your choice positioned above the navigationbar, and then when the button is tapped, you animate it downwards.

Something along the lines of this:

(Note that the ViewController has a UINavigationController as its parent here, set in the storyboard)

### ViewController.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
{
    UIView *_bottomView;
    UITableView *_dropdownView;
}

@end
```

### ViewController.m

```
@implementation ViewController

// Setup
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // The button in the top-right
    UIButton *dropboxButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    // The icon you want to use for the button
    [dropboxButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"db_nav_icon"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    // This defines which method is triggered when the button is tapped
    [dropboxButton addTarget:self action:@selector(navButtonTapped) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    dropboxButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 44, 32);
    // Wrapping the button in a UIBarButtonItem
    UIBarButtonItem *dropboxItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:dropboxButton];
    // Adding it to the navigationcontroller
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = dropboxItem;

    // Setting the original background-color to black
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    // Adding a view on top of it, because when we show the dropdown, we want to lower the opacity without fading out the dropdown (due to it being a subview of self.view)
    _bottomView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
    _bottomView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.view addSubview:_bottomView];

    // Creating the dropdown as a UITableView, and setting its delegates to this ViewController
    CGFloat dropdownHeight = (CGRectGetHeight(self.view.frame)/3);
    _dropdownView = [[UITableView alloc]
        initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -dropdownHeight, self.view.frame.size.width, dropdownHeight)
        style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    _dropdownView.delegate = self;
    _dropdownView.dataSource = self;

    [self.view addSubview:_dropdownView];
}

// Called when the button is tapped
- (void)navButtonTapped
{
    BOOL toggle = (_dropdownView.frame.origin.y == 64) ? YES : NO;
    [self toggleDropdownView:toggle animated:YES];
}

// Showing the actual dropdown view
- (void)toggleDropdownView:(BOOL)toggle animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    CGRect destination = _dropdownView.frame;
    float backgroundOpacity = (toggle) ? 1 : 0.6;
    // toggle == YES means the dropdown should appear
    destination.origin.y = (toggle) ? -destination.size.height+64 : 64;
    // If the animated-parameter is false, animate it with a duration of zero
    NSTimeInterval duration = (animated) ? 0.4 : 0;
    // Animating the opacity & dropdown position
    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{
        _dropdownView.frame = destination;
        _bottomView.layer.opacity = backgroundOpacity;
    }];
    [_dropdownView reloadData];
}

// UITableView callbacks
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 3;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [_dropdownView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellIdentifier"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"CellIdentifier"];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [self titleForCellAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}

- (NSString *)titleForCellAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)idxPath
{
    NSString *title;
    switch (idxPath.row) {
        case 0:
            title = @"Upload";
            break;
        case 1:
            title = @"Create Folder";
            break;
        case 2:
            title = @"Select";
            break;
        default:
            title = @"No title found";
            break;
    }
    return title;
}

@end
```

Comment: Awesome! Almost done...Just one thing: with your code, my original view just appears when I tap the navbar buttom, otherwhise the screen is all blank...How can I fix it? Sorry, I'm newbie...

Comment: Hey man, no probs. Is the original view you're referring to the one called `_bottomView` in the example?

In that case, could it be that you initialize it with 0 opacity? Or perhaps that you set the frame incorrectly? (Perhaps by setting its frame to `self.view.frame` instead of `self.view.bounds`?)

Comment: _bottomView is the view that you created, if I put this line of code: [self.view addSubview:_bottomView]; my view disappears...I set frame like you did

Comment: Yeah, that view is a view the size of the screen and has a white background, so its right on top of the other views. That was just a dumb example by me to simulate the modal shadow-effect of the dropbox-app. 

Another solution could be to instead temporarily fade in a black view covering the whole screen, inserted right under the dropdown-view.

However, just removing the _bottomView should show your views again.